# Create Iso from directory

Tags: terminal, disk-utility

I'm trying to create an iso from a directory on my computer. I've tried using both the Disk Utility method and just Terminal but I keep getting Operation not permitted errors regardless of my method.
I've tried adding sudo to the front of my command and even changing to root using su but I keep getting the error.

I realize that someone asked a similar question already, [how do I create an ISO/CDR file from a hard disk?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/52184/how-do-i-create-an-iso-cdr-file-from-a-hard-disk), but I need the iso I don't need to just make a backup.

EDIT3: The command that I used in Terminal is `sudo hdiutil makehybrid -iso -joliet -o /Volumes/Link/Users/magavendon/Dropbox/Mac\ Stuff/Work\ Files/Projects/CARSR/Builds/Build\ 270/Disk/lrr_01_netra_0270_a.iso New_Build270`

EDIT: I have even changed the permissions for the folder and everything contained within to 777 and the owner and group to myself.

EDIT2: As per Phoenix's suggestion, I've attempted to clear my ACLs. After running the command "sudo chmod -RN " I got:

```
chmod: Failed to clear ACL on file arp@0:arp: Invalid argument
chmod: Failed to clear ACL on file clone@0:ce: Invalid argument
chmod: Failed to clear ACL on file clone@0:eri: Invalid argument
chmod: Failed to clear ACL on file clone@0:fjgi: Invalid argument
chmod: Failed to clear ACL on file clone@0:hme: Invalid argument
chmod: Failed to clear ACL on file clone@0:ibd: Invalid argument
chmod: Failed to clear ACL on file cn@0:console: Invalid argument
chmod: Failed to clear ACL on file cn@0:syscon: Invalid argument
chmod: Failed to clear ACL on file cn@0:systty: Invalid argument
chmod: Failed to clear ACL on file cvc@0:cvc: Invalid argument
chmod: Failed to clear ACL on file cvcredir@0:cvcredir: Invalid argument
chmod: Failed to clear ACL on file devinfo@0:devinfo: Invalid argument
chmod: Failed to clear ACL on file icmp6@0:icmp6: Invalid argument
chmod: Failed to clear ACL on file icmp@0:icmp: Invalid argument
chmod: Failed to clear ACL on file ip6@0:ip6: Invalid argument
chmod: Failed to clear ACL on file ip@0:ip: Invalid argument
chmod: Failed to clear ACL on file ipsecah@0:ipsecah: Invalid argument
chmod: Failed to clear ACL on file ipsecesp@0:ipsecesp: Invalid argument
chmod: Failed to clear ACL on file keysock@0:keysock: Invalid argument
chmod: Failed to clear ACL on file ksyms@0:ksyms: Invalid argument
chmod: Failed to clear ACL on file log@0:conslog: Invalid argument
chmod: Failed to clear ACL on file log@0:log: Invalid argument
chmod: Failed to clear ACL on file mm@0:allkmem: Invalid argument
chmod: Failed to clear ACL on file mm@0:kmem: Invalid argument
chmod: Failed to clear ACL on file mm@0:mem: Invalid argument
chmod: Failed to clear ACL on file mm@0:null: Invalid argument
chmod: Failed to clear ACL on file mm@0:zero: Invalid argument
chmod: Failed to clear ACL on file openeepr@0:openprom: Invalid argument
chmod: Failed to clear ACL on file rts@0:rts: Invalid argument
chmod: Failed to clear ACL on file sad@0:admin: Invalid argument
chmod: Failed to clear ACL on file sad@0:user: Invalid argument
chmod: Failed to clear ACL on file sy@0:tty: Invalid argument
chmod: Failed to clear ACL on file sysevent@0:sysevent: Invalid argument
chmod: Failed to clear ACL on file sysmsg@0:msglog: Invalid argument
chmod: Failed to clear ACL on file sysmsg@0:sysmsg: Invalid argument
chmod: Failed to clear ACL on file tcp6@0:tcp6: Invalid argument
chmod: Failed to clear ACL on file tcp@0:tcp: Invalid argument
chmod: Failed to clear ACL on file tl@0:ticlts: Invalid argument
chmod: Failed to clear ACL on file tl@0:ticots: Invalid argument
chmod: Failed to clear ACL on file tl@0:ticotsord: Invalid argument
chmod: Failed to clear ACL on file udp6@0:udp6: Invalid argument
chmod: Failed to clear ACL on file udp@0:udp: Invalid argument
chmod: Failed to clear ACL on file wc@0:wscons: Invalid argument
chmod: Failed to clear ACL on file zfs@0:zfs: Invalid argument
```

Comment: Besides "correcting" the permissions, did you also try resetting the ACLs?  Command would be `[sudo] chmod -RN <path/to/directory>`.  Another thing to check is maybe if you have anywhere inside the directory (structure) one or more corrupted file.  Have you checked that every file does not have any odd (e.g. unintelligible) name including special characters?  Also, did you check the volume this directory is on for errors to make sure it is error free?

Comment: Which directory are you basing the ISO on? The ACL errors indicate `/dev` which would explain the problems you are having. Also, why do you use `sudo` when calling `hdiutil`?

Comment: @James, I asked for the **exact** `hdiutil` command not a _syntax/pseudo_ command line, so your "EDIT3" from a diagnostic standpoint is not complete.

Comment: Updated "Edit 3". Also, @patrix I was using `sudo` because I hoped that would make the command work. I get the same error even if I run it without `sudo`.

Comment: Are the files `rts@0:rts:` etc. part of `New_Build270`?

Comment: Hmmm. I guess none of those files exist in the directory, no.